# The best place to store a local database with an application?

Tags: wpf, database, sqlite, inno-setup

I would like to know where the best place to store a database locally is? i have an application that reads the database(SQLITE) from the Appdata/Roaming. However, this does not work on windows 7 but runs fine on windows 8 - 10. I believe it is to do with permissions and would like some extra knowledge. i am creating a setup with inno and just having problems as the programs crashes when i try to access the database on windows 7

Answer (score 2):

The [guideline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx) for storing user (that is, data users are allowed to read and write to) roaming (that is, data that is available to a user if they log on remotely) from Windows 7 on is C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming. The guideline is to create a folder with a unique name such as a GUID in this directory and store your user roaming data in that folder. You can get a path to this directory for the current user in .NET with `Path.Combine( Environment.GetFolder(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "a unique string")`.

Comment: hi, Thanks for the reply. I have created this in c# in inno the setup goes to `DefaultDirName={localappdata}` and in the C# code i have `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` The only problem is it doesn't read from the database 100% of the time as i have discovered it wont run on a windows 10 device but fine on two others i tested.

Comment: I can't test your application. You have to post code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

All users should have access to their own user directory.  Getting this should be  from related API and environment variables like [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560744(v=ws.10).aspx).  CSIDL_APPDATA should be valid across all OS versions you are coding against.  Your db probably does not need to roam, so perhaps CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA is the best choice, and the one I would use.