# Is there any other way to open a file without a specific location?

Tags: c#, wpf

So this application is going to be an .EXE file and used in other office computers. One problem though. If i would open a file, that specific computer would have another path so my code wouldn't work. Is there a way to specify only the folder? I mean like for instance `C:/ApplicationFolder/Hejj.pdf`.

I hope you understand my question.

```
private void Button_Click_8(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Danie\Desktop\Hejj.pdf");      
}
```

Comment: An `AppData` or `Users` folder location is for just this purpose

Comment: Can you use a FileOpen dialogue to prompt the user for the path?

Comment: @Plutonix can you address the solution a little more specific please?

Comment: @DougDawson That would be great but i need it to open a specific file when that button is pressed and not have the user go and search for the file manually

Comment: @DanielSaggo can you as a human locate the file on other ppl's PC without asking them or have physical access to the machine? Or do you at least know a couple places where it might be? If not then this is not doable

Comment: @Steve The thing is. This file is not on the computers but it is supposed to be in the same folder the .exe file is going to be placed. So i wanted to create a shortcut to the desktop from the folder.

Comment: Do not store user data in the application folder or on the desktop. Consult [Where is the best place to store local data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402438/).

Comment: @DourHighArch Thank you for the answer but that still doesn't solve the actual issue

Comment: use resources - even better!

Comment: resources as in the file "resources" in VS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the path of the assembly the code is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in)

Answer (score 3):

> it is supposed to be in the same folder the .exe file is going to be
>   placed

you can use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` to get the current exe's path

`Path.Combine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "Hejj.pdf")` will give you the full path of the pdf file

Comment: @DanielSaggo copy paste my code to replace your hard coded pdf path and you are done

Comment: {Process.Start(Path.Combine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "Hejj.pdf"));

Comment: like that or like so Path.Combine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "Hejj.pdf");

Comment: @DanielSaggo you gonna understand how it works. Path.Combine will give you a path. If you want to start a program then you do Process.Start({program path}).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the system special folder environment constants like

```
private void Button_Click_8(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
    Process.Start(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, Hejj.pdf));      
}
```

to get the path to the desktop directory.

*GetFolderPath* returns the path to the location. The locations of these folders can have different values on different operating systems. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.7.2) for all available directory constants.